# How to integrate firebase in an Ionic project (android/iOS)?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am reading articles and testing ways to implement analytics and push notifications in my Ionic app using firebase.

My ionic app targets both android and ios platforms, so where do I place the google-services.json firebase file? Do I have to create an 2 apps within firebase if I need to use firebase for android and iOS?

I am reading many articles some of which say root folder, whereas some mention to put it in the apps folder. Some say we have to then update the config.xml to include the foll:

```
<resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app\google-services.json" />
```

I have also read that we need to update the gradle file with application and project level dependencies.

I have put the file in platform/android/app folder and things are working correctly now.

I just want to know what is the best practice when using Ionic and Firebase, where do I place the file and what config changes do I have to make?:

1. For an Ionic android app
2. For Ionic iOS app
3. For Ionic app for both android and iOS platforms

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of the firebase plugin : 
https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

For Android, you have the `google-services.json` file, and for iOS you have the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. These files are required by firebase to work on both iOS and Android. You have to place theses files at the same level as config.xml.

> This plugin uses a hook (after prepare) that copies the configuration
>   files to the right place, namely platforms/ios/\/Resources for ios and platforms/android for android.

So you don't need the resource-file directive in your `config.xml`, since it is copied automatically.

You don't need to edit the `build.gradle` file, but If you have other google play plugins installed (like maps or admob), the compilation may not work.

> Your build may fail if you are installing multiple plugins that use
>   Google Play Services. This is caused by the plugins installing
>   different versions of the Google Play Services library. This can be
>   resolved by installing cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.
>
> If your build is still failing, you can try installing
>   cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release. For more info, read the
>   following comment about locking down the specific versions for play
>   services and firebase. It is suggested to use + instead of 15.+ to
>   ensure the correct versions are used.

EDIT : Since you're using cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics and not cordova-plugin-firebase, it seems that they didn't implement any hook to copy the files. You'll have to place these directives in your config.xml :

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app\google-services.json" />
  ...
<platform name="ios">
  <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
  ...
```

Be sure to install cordova-support-google-services

Comment: If I place the file at the same level as config.xml, then I get error when building the project that the google-services.json file is missing! Only when I place it under ..\platform\android\app does the project build OK. It looks like the hook that copies the file to the right place is only applicable when PREPARE is run? And not when we use "ionic cordova build android"

Comment: But the build step includes a prepare, so it should be copied. You can then copy it the hard way or just specify the resource-file directive to copy it automatically. Which version of the plugin are you using ?

Comment: I run "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics"; so assume its the latest package (1.0.1).

Comment: Oh well not sure the same hook is implemented on analytics. The doc I took was from the firebase plugin. Just checked analytics doc and they don’t talk about a similar feature. Sorry for the misunderstanding, you indeed have to specify the resource-file directive for both iOS and Android : platforms/android/app for Android and platforms/ios/Resources for iOS